# Sending data to a webservice using post

Tags: php, json, web-services, curl

I've been provided with an example of how to connect to a certain webserver.

It's a simple form with two inputs:

[image: Webservice Form]

It returns true after submitting the form with both the token and the json.

This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Webservice JSON</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="http://foowebservice.com/post.wd" method="post">
            <p>
                <label for="from">token: </label>
                <input type="text" id="token" name="token"><br>
                <label for="json">json: </label>
                <input type="text" id="json" name="json"><br>
                <input type="submit" value="send">
                <input type="reset">
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to make it dynamic, I'm trying to replicate it using PHP.

```
$url = "http://foowebservice.com/post.wd";

$data = array(
  'token' => 'fooToken',
  'json' => '{"foo":"test"}',
);

$content = json_encode($data);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
  array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

But I must be doing something wrong, because $response it's given a false value.

I don't mind doing this in any other way instead of using Curl.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

As suggested in the first answer, I've tried to set the $data array in this way:

```
$data = array(
  'token' => 'fooToken',
  'json' => array('foo'=>'test'),
);
```

However the response was also false.

I've tried the [Postman REST - Client plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) for Chrome, and using Development Tools / Network, the url in the headers is:

```
Request URL:http://foowebservice.com/post.wd?token=fooToken&json={%22foo%22:%22test%22}
```

Which I assume is the same url that should be sent using CURL.

Comment: you're right in your last update, that's what I wrote in my answer :)

Comment: in this case you should check your webservice.. I tested it on my apache instance and it works. I appended the working test complete code to my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the POST data in JSON format, try to pass it in the form k1=v1&k2=v2.
For example, add the following after the `$data` array definition:

```
foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $content .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
```

then remove the following lines:

```
$content = json_encode($data);
```

and

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
   array("Content-type: application/json"));
```

Complete code (tested):

**test.php**

```
<?
$url = "http://localhost/testaction.php";

$data = array(
  'token' => 'fooToken',
  'json' => '{"foo":"test"}',
);

foreach($data as $key=>$value) { $content .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($curl);

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
var_dump($response);
?>
```

**testaction.php**

```
<?
echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

**output:**

```
array(2) {
  'token' =>
  string(8) "fooToken"
  'json' =>
  string(14) "{"foo":"test"}"
}
```

Comment: This solution worked, I've made a mistake the first time I tried it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Part of `$data` is already json encoded.  Try making `$data` pure php. ie `$data['json']=array('foo'=>'test');`